# SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on schema 'SCHEMA_NAME'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

```
create or replace task landing_task
warehouse = WAREHOUSE_NAME
schedule = '1 minute'
when system$stream_has_data('landing_table2')
as 
merge into target_table tt using landing_stream ls
on tt.RECORD_CONTENT:DATA.ROW_KEY = ls.RECORD_CONTENT:DATA.ROW_KEY
WHEN MATCHED AND METADATA$ACTION = 'INSERT' AND METADATA$ISUPDATE = 'TRUE'
then update set tt.ROW_KEY = ls.ROW_KEY
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND METADATA$ACTION = 'INSERT' AND METADATA$ISUPDATE = 'FALSE'
then insert values (ls.landing_table2)
WHEN MATCHED AND METADATA$ACTION = 'DELETE' AND METADATA$ISUPDATE = 'FALSE'
then delete;
GRANT OPERATE ON SCHEMA SCHEMA_NAME TO ROLE ROLE1;
```

Getting the following error:

```
SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on schema 'DPL_SCHEMA'
```

Please help!

Comment: Have you granted access also to the database that holds the schema?

Comment: USE DATABASE DATABASE_NAME;
ALTER USER USERNAME 
SET DEFAULT_ROLE = ROLE_1;

GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE DATABASE_NAME TO ROLE ROLE_1;

Comment: Do you have all these [privileges](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro.html#owning-tasks) granted?

Comment: GRANT EXECUTE TASK, EXECUTE MANAGED TASK ON ACCOUNT TO ROLE taskadmin;  What does this command do, and which account is being talked about

Comment: There are 2 parts in the command: EXECUTE TASK - which is required to run any tasks the role owns (without it the role can't execute the task) and EXECUTE MANAGED TASK - for serverless tasks. Account refers to the account user is logged into.

Comment: Account refers to the account user is logged into. In this case if I am logged into the ACCOUNTADMIN and want to give to other roles, in this case would refer to ACCOUNTADMIN?

Comment: ACCOUNTADMIN is a role not an account. Account is explained [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier.html) but basically can be identified from the URL as **<account_identifier>**.snowflakecomputing.com.

Answer (score 0):

Likely you need to grant the USAGE privilege for the Schema to the role

[Schema Privileges](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#schema-privileges)

For example: Let's assume we have a database MY_DB, schema MY_SCHEMA  and a test role TEST_ROLE already created, then

```
use role accountadmin;
grant usage on database MY_DB to role TEST_ROLE;
grant usage on schema MY_DB.MY_SCHEMA to role TEST_ROLE; -- <<
grant select on all tables in schema MY_DB.MY_SCHEMA to role TEST_ROLE;
```

The above will grant select on all tables within a schema but to grant select to all tables in a database one should:

```
use role accountadmin;
grant usage on database MY_DB to role TEST_ROLE;
grant usage on all schemas in database MY_DB  to role TEST_ROLE; -- <<
grant select on all tables in database MY_DB to role TEST_ROLE;
```

More example can be found [here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-grant-select-on-all-future-tables-in-a-schema-and-database-level)